# Invalid Dockerrun.aws.json file

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I tried using [this package](https://github.com/micahhausler/container-transform) to generate a working `Dockerrun.aws.json` file. However, I'm running into some issues.

Dockerrun.aws.json

```
{
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "command": [
                "./wait-for-it.sh",
                "db:5432",
                "--",
                "./EXECUTABLE"
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "image": "gregpmillr/IMG",
            "memory": 512,
            "links": [
                "db"
            ],
            "name": "app",
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 8080,
                    "hostPort": 443
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "POSTGRES_DB",
                    "value": "db"
                },
                {
                    "name": "POSTGRES_USER",
                    "value": "dbuser"
                },
                {
                    "name": "POSTGRES_PASSWORD",
                    "value": "dbpw"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "image": "postgres",
            "memory": 512,
            "name": "db",
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 5432,
                    "hostPort": 6000
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "family": "",
    "volumes": []
}
```

After running `eb deploy` I get the error:

> ERROR   Invalid Dockerrun.aws.json version, abort deployment

Any ideas why this may be incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Elastic Beanstalk `Dockerrun.aws.json`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_v2config.html) for multi-container Docker setups must include a key value pair for `"AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2`.

Also, I don't believe `"family"` or `"containerDefinitions.command"` are supported for Elastic Beanstalk. It looks like you've created a [task definition for Amazon ECS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definitions.html), a service that differs in configuration and deployment from Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: As I understand it, fields that are valid in ECS are valid in Elastic Beanstalk definitions as well: 
"The container definition and volumes sections of Dockerrun.aws.json use the same formatting as the corresponding sections of an Amazon ECS task definition file." (from the page you linked under "Container Definition Format"